# Getting error when using Rsync and Python

Tags: python, linux, rsync

When I try to use rsync (Linux Mint) in Python I get the following error

> rsync: [sender] change_dir "home/user/my_source_folder" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Here is the code I used

```
#!/bin/bash -l
import os, subprocess
from lib.eml import Eml
        

def sync_from_external_hd():
    src = "home/user/my_source_folder/"
    dst = "/home/user/backup folder"

    if os.path.exists(dst) and os.path.exists(src):
        subprocess.Popen(["rsync", "-a", f"remote_user@[ip address]:{src}", dst], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


sync_from_external_hd()
```

I know the directory exists because I copy & paste the directory from the error & it opens.  I've also tried the rsync command in a terminal & it works.  Also, I already have a SSH connection between the two systems

Comment: missing slash before `home/...` in `src`? also, `/home/user/backup folder` may not play nicely with that command due to the space in there, i'd recommend renaming it to `/home/user/backup_folder` both in the filesystem and in this code.

Comment: Why is there `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: @IvanBalepin They're passing the arguments as individual list elements, not using shell parsing, so the space shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If you are logging in as `/home/user`, then when you login, you will be in that home directory, so just use `src="my_source_folder/"`.  Also note that it matters to rsync if you have a slash at the end of the paths.  You'll need to check that.

Comment: Your code has `src = "home/user/my_source_folder/"`. Why isn't there a leading slash in that path? That lack of a leadnig slash would appear to be the source of the error.

Comment: @IvanBalepin Thanks, I left it off by mistake when I was changing the path for posting but it is in my original code

Comment: @Cyrus  I run this as a script in crontab, so it needs the shell info to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a mistake on my part.  The problem was the source I was referencing existed on the client, not the remote server.  I didn't realize that I was logging into the remote server using the ip address.  I'm still kind of new to Linux.  Here is the code I used

```
#!/bin/bash -l
import os, subprocess
from lib.eml import Eml
    

def sync_from_external_hd():
    src = "home/user/my_source_folder/"
    dst = "/home/user/backup folder"

    if os.path.exists(dst) and os.path.exists(src):
        subprocess.Popen(["rsync", "-a", src, dst], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


sync_from_external_hd()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using an absolute path for the source directory instead of a relative path. You can use the os.path.abspath() function to convert the relative path to an absolute path. Here's an updated version of your code with the absolute path:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
import os, subprocess
from lib.eml import Eml

def sync_from_external_hd():
src = os.path.abspath("/home/user/my_source_folder/")
dst = "/home/user/backup folder"

if os.path.exists(dst) and os.path.exists(src):
    subprocess.Popen(["rsync", "-a", f"remote_user@[ip address]:{src}", 
dst], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
sync_from_external_hd()
```

This code should work correctly as long as the source directory path is correct and the SSH connection is properly established.

Comment: Thanks Parag.  With this, I'm getting the error "rsync: [sender] change_dir "/home/user/" failed: No such file or directory (2)"  So it appears to be trying to change to the parent of the directory that I'm trying to access (for some reason).  But it even says that that directory doesn't exist (it does).  I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm accessing the destination directory via sshfs.  Also, because the server's key is already in my authorized_keys folder on the client, I assumed that I didn't have explicitly establish a ssh connection.